# VSCode extension - How do I edit workspace global config?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am developing a vscode plug-in. How do I modify the “user” settings through code?

I can get/modify the workspace's configuration, but the problem is with the user settings since they are global.

What I'm trying to set up:

```
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('Lua.workspace.library', [libraryPath]);
```

Reference image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`update()` has this signature:

> update(section: string, value: any, configurationTarget?:
> ConfigurationTarget | boolean | null, overrideInLanguage?: boolean):
> Thenable

You want to use a `configurationTarget` of `vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global` or `true` to change the "User" settings, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ConfigurationTarget

`await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('Lua.workspace.library', [libraryPath], vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);`

or

`await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('Lua.workspace.library', [libraryPath], true);`

I suggest also adding `await` so the changes are made before the rest of your code starts to run.

Comment: Thank you! I have more than 2 weeks looking for this answer until now.
Thanks to your answer I finally find out that in getConfiguration() have to be blank in order to work